# FTDI Dual UART/FIFO: conflict with ftdi_sio

Tags: linux, usb, uart, ftdi

I have a FPGA-Board with two serial connection over one USB-Connection.

Problem:
A program needed to flash the FPGA-Program doesn't work if ftdi_sio is loaded.
This program uses the first connection.

The other one, ttyUSB1, is needed to communicate with the FPGA directly (e.g. with Putty)

But this only works if the ftdi_sio is loaded and the ttyUSB* is available, which it isn't if I have disabled ftdi_so with this udev-rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind'"
```

So:
Without this rule

- I have ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1
- Programming (Lattice Programmer) doesn't work
- Serial connection with ttyUSB1 to the FPGA works

With this rule

- I have no ttyUSB*
- Programming with the Programmer works
- Serial connection to the FPGA does not work (no tty)

Is there a way to only disable ftdi_sio for one connection?
Or is there a way to disable/enable it with a command without reconnecting the USB-cable?

Currently I use a windows VM to program the FPGA but this is very annoying

If you need more information about the device, tell me.

aligator

Comment: your rule currently matches both interfaces. change it to only match the interface you want to unbind

Answer (score 2):

you can load and unload kernel modules manually with `modprobe` i.e. load with `modprobe ftdi_sio` and unload it with `modprobe -r ftdi_sio`

a problem could be that you need to load **dependent modules** also

to check the dependencies of `ftdi_sio` run `lsmod`

( http://xmodulo.com/how-to-check-kernel-module-dependencies-on-linux.html )